# Eclipse Luna dark theme, code editor white

Tags: eclipse, themes, eclipse-luna

I downloaded the new Eclipse Luna (ver. 4.4) and changed to Dark Theme, but the code editor is not changing. See the screen-shot:

[image]

I tried this on MAC, Windows and Linux, always the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Luna dark theme (not completely dark like pictures)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470710/eclipse-luna-dark-theme-not-completely-dark-like-pictures)

Comment: ypu have to download the theme for the code editor you want from http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Comment: @greg-449 you are right its a duplicate, but its bit hard to describe the problem

Comment: @FelixLahmer I downloaded the .epf file, how can i apply it ?

Comment: @kozla13 find it here http://vimeo.com/19168132

Comment: @FelixLahmer Actually the dark theme in Eclipse Luna is **supposed** to work **without** any additional downloads. It was one of the [highly advertised features](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/20/dark-theme-top-eclipse-luna-feature-5/). It's quite frustrating it doesn't...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can download [Eclipse Color Theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) plugin as a workaround. It worked fine for me.

After installing Eclipse Color Theme you have to go to: `Preferences` -> `Appearance` -> `Color Theme`, then chose the whatever theme you like, from the screenshot I chose `Monokai`

[image]

Comment: Hm this looks like my answer with a screenshot ;)

Comment: @Yes, you are right, but you had upvotes at least :P

Comment: That toolbar is annoying, can u make that dark too?

Comment: @raffian yes, but it isn't related to Eclipse stuff, you need to change your Windows theme

Comment: I don't know how you get the theme applied to all the views. The issue I opened at https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/209 proves that it is not possible. Only active editor window has the selected theme applied and not project/package browser, etc.

Comment: @Javix you have to configure the Dark theme (included in Eclipse) and then install the Eclipse Color Theme to fix the editor. That fixed the issue for me, I haven't configured any additional thing. I've done this in 5 workstation (with windows, linux and mac)

Comment: @Fede, if you choose Eclipse Dark theme, it will change the color of all the views as needed (eveni it is not very nice to see :)). But if you choose no matter which theme from the list of Eclipse Color Theme plugin, you will have editor and package views colors different. Why ? Because Eclipse Color Theme plugin applies ONLY to the editor view and as exception to the console. If somebody likes it, it is OK, but not for me. I think, the real result would be to have ALL the perspectives/views with the same color theme applied and not a mix of 2 themes.

Comment: @Javix my answer was about to fix the issue posted by OP. I'm not saying if the dark theme is good, bad, ugly or cool, I've just posted the solution to this question. Btw, If you have downvoted you should review SO principles. Anyway, feel free to create a question with your doubts so community can give you a hand

Comment: @Fede: No I've not downvoted, just posted to let the others know more details about the issue and tried to explain what exactly one can get when applying the proposed solution. More of that, the screenshot you posted seems to be Spring IDE (Spring Tools Suite) and not Eclipse Luna. May be there are no differences in technical terms.

Comment: @Fede: when using this dark juno theme i cant see the graphical view of xml files , is there any solution for this?

Comment: @aravindvarma no idea, I think you should create a question with that

Comment: This is by far the best approach I've ever seen. It gives me Sublime Text like color theme.

Answer (score 39):

Ok here's what worked for me.  (on java 8 JRE on WinXP)

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors: Background colour

deselect 'system default' and choose pure black

Now go to 'current line highlight' and make it your favourite shade of grey. RGB 60/60/60 works for me.

Comment: The optimal background color for me was RGB 32/32/32 as the line number background was the same and doesnt look ugly anymore. But still there are far too many tweaks to do to be able to use this theme (at least on windows machines).

Comment: Yes agree, it still needs so much work.  I gave up on the dark theme in the end as i couldn't figure out how to change the colour for the current line highlight for the code-complete pop-ups.  Both the foreground and background colours are almost the same.  I think eclipse still picks these colours from the windows theme rather than it's own themeing settings.

Answer (score 9):

You can download a dark color scheme for eclipse [color scheme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin)
That did help me when i switched to black.

Comment: Upvoted your comment because it was first and this has happened to me various times.  Better luck next time.

Comment: btw, I have put together a very nice black theme of my own: https://github.com/davidcoleman007/VibrantNight  If you are a fan of black UI, check it out!

Comment: this site is down. can you upload the oblivion file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Instead if finding a working night theme I discovered a utility that puts my entire desktop into night mode [NegativeScreen](https://zerowidthjoiner.net/negativescreen).

[image: eclipse ide night mode]

I use the below adjusted 'Smart Inversion Alt 2' matrix where the black is lightened a little the best for my tastes.

```
Smart Inversion Alt 2b (danielsokolowski)=
{  0.390, -0.620, -0.620,  0.000,  0.000 }
{ -1.210, -0.220, -1.220,  0.000,  0.000 }
{ -0.160, -0.160,  0.840,  0.000,  0.000 }
{  0.075,  0.075,  0.075,  1.000,  0.000 }
{  1,  1,  1,  0.000,  1.000 }
```